# Is there a 100% working Spotify program for 19.04?

Tags: crash, spotify

I have a Spotify Premium account which I want to use in my Ubuntu 19.04 distribution. I do have a problem though. I can't seem to find a version of Spotify for Ubuntu that works as it should. The Spotify-Version from the package `spotify-client-gnome-support` keeps crashing directly after opening it. If I try to start it over and over again, there's like a 5% chance it won't crash which is pretty annoying, but sadly it is the only one that actually plays music if it doesn't crash. The version from the software center shows the interface without crashing but doesn't let me play any songs, telling me that "Spotify can't play this right now". Same thing happens when I install it via snap.

Does anyone else have such problems with Spotify on their Ubuntu installation or is it just me?

I'll appreciate any help!

-

Edit: I am dumb. I tried the software center version again and noticed that the permissions for playing/recording sound were set to "(disconnected)" by default instead of being directed to pulseaudio. It's working perfectly fine now. Thanks for your suggestions anyways!

Comment: From your description so far, it's s spotify problem. Are there eeror messages? Logs? (Make spotify fail, then `journalctl --since="-5 minutes"`, then edit out the noise). Are there version numbers? Pick ONE version to intsall and debug. Remember to edit your post https://askubuntu.com/posts/1170902/edit and format

Comment: The spotify snap works for me on 19.04. I'm not a fan of snap at all, but sometimes it is the best choice.

Comment: You can answer your own question and you can accept your own answer as the solution after it has been posted for a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spotify's own client?

Create `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`  with:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

and put the following into the file:

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free #Spotify
```

Then run `Software Updater` and install their client.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but the problem was actually quite simple and I managed to solve it. See the edit I made.